# Can't find what could cause the "caused by an out-of-range assignment or out-of-range array lookup." error

Tags: uppaal

I get this error when I try to check my system for deadlocks:

> The verification was aborted due to an error. Most likely, this is
>   caused by an out-of-range assignment or out-of-range array lookup.

I understand what this error is supposed to mean (thanks to https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/help.php?file=System_Descriptions/Expressions.shtml ), but I really can't find any situation where this problem could happen and can't get it to occur by playing with the simulator.
The only thing I can think of that could cause this problem is one of my arrays, but from what I've seen it seems safe to assume I never do any out of bounds.

Is there any way to find any clue to help me identify my problem (a more precise error, the trace that caused this problem, or something like that) ? Or maybe there is a detail I missed, and this error can be caused by something else ?

Comment: what version of Uppaal are you using? 4.1 should be able to tell you more precisely and even give you the trace.

Comment: @mariusm I had several questions, but decided to check everything by myself, and it turns out you were right, the snapshot version have pretty much everything I asked for. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like mariusm said, the version 4.1 (snapshot) have a detailed error dump, and let you have a trace causing the error.

My problem is solved, and this topic no longer useful.